# How to pass value from adapter to another class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get switch state from item view

this is the layout file which holds the switch and i wanted to get if switch is checked from another class

i want to either do it in the  adapter and to pass a value from the adapter to another class by checking if the switch is checked or get the layout from class and check if the switch is checked

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/studentName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Student Name"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/attendanceSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:checked="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<User> users;
    public StudentAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
        this.context = context;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.student_item, parent, false);
        return new StudentAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final User user = users.get(position);


        holder.studentName.setText(user.getStudentname() + " " + user.getLastname());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView studentName;
        public Switch aSwitch;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            studentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
            aSwitch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendanceSwitch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Shared Preferences to store values

Comment: how @EraldDeveloper

Comment: See some examples first, https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

use SharedPreferences

```
public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
public SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
```

store data

```
PrefsEditor.putString("value", "MyString").apply();
```

get data

```
String value = sharedpreferences.getString("value", "");
```